# How to access an object from a different class and package?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

So, I am a learning programmer and I started to learn Java 2 months ago as a course at my university. I really like to program in my spare time and I'm currently trying to make a game. There is one problem at the moment which I just can't solve.

I have a class called Move, and I declare in my class called Start:
Move move1 = new Move();

Now when I'm back in my Move class, I would like to access this move1 but it doesn't let me. It says:classname cannot be resolved.

To clarify:

```
public class Move {
    private String s = null;
    public void setName(String s) {
       name = s;
    }
    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }
    public void setList() {
    System.out.println(move1.getName() + move2.getName()); // This won't work
    }
}
```

And the start class:

```
public class Start {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Move move1 = new Move();
      Move move2 = new Move();
      move1.setName(kick);
      move2.setName(punch);
   }
}
```

It would be awesome if someone could help me out!

-edit

OK! I got a few reactions but I didn't really get the answer I need. I know now i can use `this` instead of the object name but what if I want to use a second object? I changed code the above.

Comment: Inside Move class you can do just: System.out.println(getName());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the names move1 and move2 are out of scope in the setList method.  They're defined in Start.main as local variables, so they are only visible there.

There are a innumerable ways you can solve this.  The most straight-forward way is to move the setList method to Start.  Because you're calling it from main, which is a static method, setList will also have to be static.

`public class Start {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Move move1 = new Move();
      Move move2 = new Move();
      move1.setName(kick);
      move2.setName(punch);
      setList(move1, move2);
   }
   public static void setList(Move move1, Move move2) {
          System.out.println(move1.getName() + move2.getName());
   }
}`

If you think setList should be in the Move class, you'll need to pass the second move as a parameter.

`public class Move {
   ...
   public void setList(Move other) {
       System.out.println(this.getName() + other.getName());
   }
}`

Comment: Thank you so much! You explained first of all very nice why my code doesn't work and gave me two possible solutions. Now I can continue! Ty

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to say `move1.getName()`. You can say `this.getName()` instead. The keyword `this` refers to whatever object is calling the method - in this case, `move1`.

This is because the object `move1` only exists in the scope of the main method in `Start`. Therefore, "move1" is meaningless anywhere other than `main`.

In reality, the keyword `this` can be omitted; you could just say `getName()` without putting anything in front of it.

Comment: Thank you for responding! But then what do I do when I want to print another name of another object like:'System.out.println(move1.getName() + move2.getName());' where move2 is also an object from Move.

Comment: @user3339355 What you should do is make either an array or an `ArrayList` of all the moves, and store it either in `Start` or `Move`, but declare it as `static`. (Declaring things as static makes it so that there's only one list, not one for each move - it's a class variable, not an instance variable.) Then, make the method `setList` static as well, and have it print all the items in the list.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I will try this as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

`move1` is the object of `Move` class define in the `Start` class so you cant access it.You can simply access the method of Move class with below line.

```
System.out.println(getName()); // THis will work
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access current move object (move1) is using `this` key word. You could say `System.out.println(this.getName());` in Move class.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you didn't add import of class Move? It necessary when you access an object from a different package.

Comment: These classes are probably in the same package.  The names move1 and move2 are just out of scope.  The setList method doesn't really belong in the move class as written.